# PHP $_REQUEST['do']

Tags: php

I'm a PHP beginner. I don't see the answer to this question in the php manual.

I know what a REQUEST superglobal does, but is 'do' something built into PHP? I found this code in a tutorial...

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['do']) && ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'add') )
```

Does 'do' just mean that the form has been submitted? In the case of information coming from a link...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any values set in `$_COOKIE`, `$_GET`, and `$_POST` will show up in `$_REQUEST` which means that a form that submits data to the page likely has an input element with a key of `'do'` like in this example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="add" />
```

Of course it could be *any* html form element with a name of `do`, or any cookie with a name of `do`, or just a static query string with a name of `do`.

Comment: thanks, this is what I wanted to know. "do" is a value set by the user.

Answer (score 2):

That's means a GET/POST/COOKIE (GPC) name 'do' has been submitted.

The PHP manual is very good, and can give you many answers:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

When you submit a "request" (url with persistent COOKIES, URL-based GET variables, and POST'd variables from forms or other means), your browser sends HTML headers that contain key/value pairs that are identifiable by type (GPC) and then by name (to get a value).

So a GET variable may be presented by:

http://www.example.com/?do=yes

And the server with PHP will allow you access that `do` variable by:

```
$do = $_GET['do'];
```

Or:

```
$do = $_REQUEST['do'];
```

My preference is to use the actual method it was presented, ie, the `$_GET['do']` call, not `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: I saw that page in the manual, but it doesn't explain if "do" is always part of REQUEST. The answer by zzzzBov told me what I wanted to know. Namely, that "do" is set by the programmer.

Comment: `GPC` is controlled by the request, ie, what gets included in the header of the request that is submitted to the server. GET is part of the URL, POST is data that is "attached" to the request, and COOKIEs are within the header itself. There are no specific key/values that are just part of any/all requests. If the server or user (by way of form or Javascript) don't put it there, it's not part of the request.

Answer (score 1):

It would be something submitted either via GET or POST. $_REQUEST combines both.